# Null distribution related question (edited)

Tags: r, null, distribution

Please help with the following question.

The experiment involved mice; feeding them two diets: high-fat diet and normal diet (control group). The data below contains the weights of all female mice (population) that received the normal diet. The data can be downloaded from GitHub running the following command lines in R:

```
library(downloader)

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleControlsPopulation.csv"
filename <- basename(url)
download(url, destfile = filename)
x <- unlist(read.csv(filename))
```

Here x represents the weights of the entire population.

So, the question is:

Set the seed at 1, then using a for-loop take a random sample of 5 mice 1,000 (one thousand) times. Save the averages.

What proportion of these 1,000 averages are more than 1 gram away from the average x?

Below is what I have tried using the ‘sum’ & ‘mean()’ function:

```
set.seed(1)

n <- 1000
sample1 <- vector("numeric", n)  
for (i in 1: n) {
    sample1[i] <- mean (sample (x, 5))
  }

sum(sample1 > mean(x) / n)
mean(sample1 > mean(x)+1)
```

So this step is where I need the help…because I am not sure how to deal with ‘1 gram away from average of x’ statement in the question.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like homework, so I'll give some hints:

In your second code block, the last two statements seem off.

```
n <- 1000
sample1 <- vector("numeric", n)  
for (i in 1: n) {
    sample1[i] <- mean (sample (x, 5))
  }

sum(sample1 > mean(x) / n)  #<- why dividing by n here?
mean(sample1 > mean(x)+1)   #<- what are you trying to do here?
```

Why are you dividing the mean of the overall sample by n?
The call to mean does seem to make sense.

I don't think you need the second statement, `mean(sample1 > mean(x)+1)` to get your answer.

You need an inequality in the `sum()` statement that will be TRUE for every value that is outside the range of `mean(x) - 1` to `mean(x) + 1`.  Or, the number less than `mean(x) -1` plus the number greater than `mean(x) + 1`.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

On the loop part you are doing correctly, for the ##What proportion of these 1,000 averages are more than 1 gram away from the average x?##`sum(abs(null)-mean(population)>1)/n`

Comment: sorry I put the abs function to the wrong place, I think you can figure it out very quickly